# Error 401 Unauthorized when sending Axios GET request

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, axios, http-status-code-401

I'm working with a ReactJS project using axios to get data from MongoDB.

I have a login component that calls a startLogin function, which in summary has two axios request to log me in the app, a POST request to send the user data and a GET request to access the user information. The POST request works fine with a 200 status code, but for some reason the GET request responds with a 401 error code. I have the backend project with API Rest working on a server 187:3000, and the front project fails when I try to send requests to the backend server from an external origin, I mean, if I use the React project on the same server as the API is running, there is no problem, but when I want to do it from other server, or from localhost, the story is different.

Here is my API routes code:

index.js

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const authRouter = require("./authRouter");
const apiRouter = require("./apiRouter");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const {
  changeSubscriptionStatus,
} = require("../controllers/subscriptionController");
const mtto = false;

module.exports = function (app) {
  //SOLUCION CORS
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://10.10.251.194:5173");

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
    );

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization, X-Auth-Token, Cookie"
    );

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
  });
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "100kb" }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use("/auth", authRouter);
  app.use("/api", apiRouter);

  // routing static assets from build
  app.use(
    express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../build"), {
      index: false,
    })
  );

  // webpack hot reloading hack
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "hot") {
    const webpack = require("webpack");
    const webpackConfig = require("../../webpack.config");
    const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

    app.use(
      require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler, {
        noInfo: true,
        publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
      })
    );
    app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));
  }

  app.post("/transactions/pending", changeSubscriptionStatus);

  app.get("*", auth.optionalJwt, function (req, res, next) {
    // console.log(req.originalUrl)
    if (mtto)
      return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../mtto/index.html"));
    if (req.user) {
      return res.sendFile(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "../../build/dashboard/index.html")
      );
    }
    return res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, "../../build/public/index.html")
    );
  });
};
```

passport.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const ApiError = require("../util/ApiError");
const User = require("../models/user");
const { LoginErrorCode } = require("../constants/enums");

var jwtCookieExtractor = function (req) {
  var token = null;
  if (req && req.cookies) token = req.cookies.jwt;
  return token;
};

const jwtOptions = {
  issuer: process.env.JWT_ISSUER,
  secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  jwtFromRequest: jwtCookieExtractor,
};

passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function (payload, done) {
    if (!payload.userId) return done(ApiError.Unauthorized());
    User.findOne({ _id: payload.userId })
      .populate("company")
      .exec()
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) return done(ApiError.Unauthorized());
        done(null, user);
      })
      .catch(done);
  })
);

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
    },
    (email, password, done) => {
      email = email.trim().toLowerCase();
      if (!email || !password)
        return done(
          new ApiError(400, "Favor de escribir su correo electrónico")
        );
      var user;
      User.findOne({ email })
        .select("+password")
        .then((foundUser) => {
          if (!foundUser)
            return Promise.reject(
              ApiError.Unauthorized(
                "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos",
                LoginErrorCode.INCORRECT
              )
            );
          user = foundUser;
          return user.isValidPassword(password);
        })
        .then((isValid) => {
          if (!isValid)
            return Promise.reject(
              ApiError.Unauthorized(
                "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos",
                LoginErrorCode.INCORRECT
              )
            );
          if (!user.is_verified)
            return Promise.reject(
              ApiError.Unauthorized(
                "Verificación de correo electrónico pendiente.",
                LoginErrorCode.NOT_VERIFIED
              )
            );
          done(null, user);
        })
        .catch(done);
    }
  )
);
```

user.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const moment = require("moment");
const ApiError = require("../util/ApiError");
const commonModelOptions = require("../util/commonModelOptions");
const mailgun = require("mailgun-js")({
  apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
  domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN,
});
const { Position } = require("../constants/enums");

const Company = require("./company");
const Invite = require("./invite");

const ExpirableTokenSchema = new Schema(
  {
    token: { type: String, required: true },
    expires_at: { type: Date, required: true },
  },
  {
    _id: false,
  }
);

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now, select: false },
    company: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Company" },
    position: { type: Number, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
    recovery_token: { type: ExpirableTokenSchema, select: false },
    is_verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    verification_token: { type: ExpirableTokenSchema, select: false },
    last_login: { type: Date },
  },
  commonModelOptions
);

UserSchema.methods.jwtToken = function () {
  return jwt.sign({ userId: this.id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "365d",
    issuer: process.env.JWT_ISSUER,
  });
};
```

authRouther.js

```
const express = require("express");
const authRouter = express.Router();
const authController = require("../controllers/authController");
const apiErrorHandler = require("../middleware/apiErrorHandler");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

authRouter.get("/", auth.jwt, authController.userInfo);
authRouter.post("/", authController.login);
authRouter.put("/", authController.resetPassword);
authRouter.delete("/", auth.jwt, authController.logout);
authRouter.put("/profile", auth.jwt, authController.editUser);
authRouter.get("/logout", authController.logout);
authRouter.post(
  "/users",
  authController.validateRegister,
  authController.register
);
authRouter.post("/recover", authController.recover);
authRouter.put("/password", auth.jwt, authController.changePassword);
authRouter.post(
  "/invite",
  authController.validateRegister,
  authController.registerWithInvite
);
authRouter.post("/verification", authController.resendVerification);
authRouter.post("/verification/:token", authController.verify);

authRouter.use(apiErrorHandler);

module.exports = authRouter;`
```

authController.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const ApiError = require("../util/ApiError");
const validator = require("validator");
const User = require("../models/user");
const notMissing = require("../util/notMissing");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const login = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return next(info);
    res.cookie("jwt", user.jwtToken());
    let accounts = { 30: "invited", 40: "admin", 100: "sysadmin" }; //solis
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: user.id },
      { $set: { last_login: new Date() } }
    ).then();
    res.json({
      ok: true,
      typeAccount: accounts[user.position],
      token: user.jwtToken(),
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};

const logout = (req, res, next) => {
  res.cookie("jwt", "");
  res.json({ ok: true });
};

const validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
  let data = req.body.data || req.body;
  data.name = data.name ? data.name.trim() : "";
  // Start validating
  if (!data.name) return next(new ApiError(400, "Ingresa tu nombre completo"));
  if (!data.password) return next(new ApiError(400, "Ingresa tu contraseña"));
  if (!data.confirm)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "Ingresa la confirmación de tu contraseña"));
  if (data.password !== data.confirm)
    return next(
      new ApiError(400, "La contraseña y la confirmación no coinciden")
    );
  if (data.password.length < 8)
    return next(
      new ApiError(400, "La contraseña debe incluir mínimo 8 caracteres")
    );
  next();
};

const register = (req, res, next) => {
  req.body.email = req.body.email ? req.body.email.toLowerCase().trim() : "";
  if (!req.body.email)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "Ingresa tu correo electrónico"));
  if (!validator.isEmail(req.body.email))
    return next(
      new ApiError(400, "La dirección de correo electrónico no es válida")
    );
  User.register(req.body)
    .then((user) => res.json({ ok: true }))
    .catch(next);
};

const recover = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.email)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "Ingresa tu correo electrónico"));
  let user;
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    .then((foundUser) => {
      if (!foundUser)
        return Promise.reject(
          new ApiError(
            404,
            `No hay un usuario registrado con el correo ${req.body.email}`
          )
        );
      user = foundUser;
      return user.generateRecoveryToken();
    })
    .then((token) => user.sendRecoveryEmail(token))
    .then((_) => res.json({ ok: true }))
    .catch(next);
};

const resetPassword = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.token)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "No se encontró el token"));
  if (!req.body.password)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "Ingresa tu nueva constraseña"));
  if (!req.body.confirm)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "Confirma tu nueva contraseña"));
  if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirm)
    return next(
      new ApiError(400, "La contraseña y la confirmación no coinciden")
    );
  let user;
  let now = new Date();
  User.findOne({
    "recovery_token.token": req.body.token,
    "recovery_token.expires_at": { $gt: now },
  })
    .then((foundUser) => {
      if (!foundUser)
        return Promise.reject(
          new ApiError(
            404,
            `El token es inválido o ya ha expirado. Intenta nuevamente.`
          )
        );
      user = foundUser;
      return user.changePassword(req.body.password);
    })
    .then((_) => res.json({ ok: true }))
    .catch(next);
};

const changePassword = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.current_password)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "Ingresa tu contraseña anterior"));
  if (!req.body.new_password)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "Ingresa tu nueva contraseña"));
  if (!req.body.confirm)
    return next(new ApiError(400, "Confirma tu nueva contraseña"));
  if (req.body.new_password !== req.body.confirm)
    return next(
      new ApiError(400, "La contraseña y la confirmación no coinciden")
    );
  req.user
    .isValidPassword(req.body.current_password)
    .then((isValid) => {
      if (!isValid)
        return Promise.reject(
          new ApiError(403, "La contraseña anterior es incorrecta")
        );
      return req.user.changePassword(req.body.new_password);
    })
    .then((_) => res.json({ ok: true }))
    .catch(next);
};

const userInfo = (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(req.user);
};

const editUser = (req, res, next) => {
  req.user.name = req.body.name;
  return req.user
    .save()
    .then((user) => res.json(user))
    .catch(next);
};

const registerWithInvite = (req, res, next) => {
  notMissing(req.body, [
    "token",
    "data",
    "data.name",
    "data.password",
    "data.confirm",
  ])
    .then((_) => User.registerWithInvite(req.body.token, req.body.data))
    .then((user) => {
      res.cookie("jwt", user.jwtToken());
      res.json(user);
    })
    .catch(next);
};

const verify = (req, res, next) => {
  let now = new Date();
  User.findOne({
    "verification_token.token": req.params.token,
    "verification_token.expires_at": { $gt: now },
  })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user)
        return Promise.reject(
          new ApiError(
            404,
            "El enlace de verificación es inválido o ya ha expirado. Intenta iniciar sesión nuevamente para solicitar el reenvío."
          )
        );
      user.is_verified = true;
      return user.save();
    })
    .then((user) => {
      res.cookie("jwt", user.jwtToken());
      return res.json({ ok: true });
    })
    .catch(next);
};

const resendVerification = (req, res, next) => {
  notMissing(req.body, ["email"])
    .then((_) =>
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email, is_verified: { $ne: true } })
    )
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user)
        return Promise.reject(
          new ApiError(
            404,
            "El usuario ya está verificado o no está registrado con ese correo electrónico."
          )
        );
      return Promise.all([user, user.renewVerificationToken()]);
    })
    .then(([user, token]) => user.sendVerificationEmail(token))
    .then((_) => res.json({ ok: true }))
    .catch(next);
};

const authController = {
  login,
  logout,
  register,
  validateRegister,
  registerWithInvite,
  recover,
  resetPassword,
  changePassword,
  userInfo,
  editUser,
  verify,
  resendVerification,
};

module.exports = authController;
```

auth.js

```
    const passport = require("passport");
    const ApiError = require("../util/ApiError");
    const { CompanyStatus } = require("../constants/enums");
    
    function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
      console.log(req);
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
      next(new ApiError(401, "Unauthenticated"));
    }
    
    function optionalJwt(req, res, next) {
      if (req.cookies && req.cookies.jwt) {
        return passport.authenticate(
          "jwt",
          { session: false },
          (err, user, info) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.user = user;
            return next();
          }
        )(req, res, next);
      }
      return next();
    }
    
    function hasPosition(position) {
      return (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.user.position < position) {
          return next(ApiError.Forbidden("Permisos insuficientes"));
        }
        next();
      };
    }
    
    function belongsToCompanyWithPosition(position = 0) {
      return (req, res, next) => {
        if (
          req.user.company.id !== req.params.companyId ||
          req.user.position < position
        ) {
          return next(ApiError.Forbidden("Permisos insuficientes"));
        }
        next();
      };
    }
    
    function companyIsActive(req, res, next) {
      if (req.user.company.status !== CompanyStatus.ACTIVE) {
        return next(ApiError.Forbidden("Tu cuenta está desactivada"));
      }
      next();
    }
    
    module.exports = {
      jwt: passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
      isAuthenticated,
      optionalJwt,
      hasPosition,
      belongsToCompanyWithPosition,
      companyIsActive,
    };
```

And this is my Front code:

ctCloudApi.js

```
import axios from "axios";

let url = "http://10.10.251.187:3000";

const ctCloudApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: url,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

useAuthStore.js

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { ctCloudApi } from "../apis";
import {
  onChecking,
  onLogin,
} from "../redux";

export const useAuthStore = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const startLogin = async ({ email, password }) => {
    try {
      // Se llama a la api
      const resp = await ctCloudApi.post("/auth", { email, password });
      console.log(resp);
      const token = resp.data.token;
      if (resp.data.ok) {
        dispatch(onChecking()); // Se llama a la accion para volver todos los estados por defecto
        const resp = await ctCloudApi.get(`/auth`, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });
        if (resp.status === 200) {
          dispatch(onLogin(resp.data));
          return;
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(
        setMessage({
          type: "login",
          msg: error.message,
        })
      );
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(clearMessage());
      }, 2000);
      return;
    }
  };
```

This is the error message I get:
[image]

And these are the axios request sent, with their responses:
[image]
[image]

[image]

I'm trying to communicate with the API using axios, and I get 401 status code

Comment: First you can uninstall bodyParser since express now include already this functionnality, just add : app.use(express.json()); on your middleware, 2nd how do you set to your final road middleware with /auth route ? like app.use(/auth, authRouter) ? since i don't see it in your select file

Comment: @ShueiYang Hmm, I don't think I really understand your 2nd question; if you mean the middleware I use to verify if the user is authenticated like 'authRouter.get("/", auth.jwt, authController.userInfo);', auth.jwt comes from an auth.js file that exports an object called 'jwt: passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false })'

Comment: @ShueiYang Oh ok, I updated my post to show the auth,js code, I hope that's what your talking about.

Comment: @ShueiYang Ok, that's in my index.js file, but I didn't show it because i didn't want to paste a vary large piece of code, but I already updated so you can see the rest :)

Comment: I clean out my discussion, too much text sry, looks like for some reason you don't have your jwt attached to your get userinfo on cross domain, i can't figure it out now with jwt auth, you can now remove the extra part from index.js, can you just show more on your authController.js with userinfo, and don't remove the authRouter.js part below so other people can also see it

Comment: @ShueiYang Ok, I just edited and updated my authController.js and authRouter.js files so you can se the entire code, if you can help I will really aprecciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set this up for the cookie setting and check how it go :

```
  const login = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return next(info);
    res.cookie("jwt", user.jwtToken(),{
      maxAge: 30000, // 30 sec to test
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true, // only for https
      sameSite: "none"  // false or lax for development
  });
    let accounts = { 30: "invited", 40: "admin", 100: "sysadmin" }; //solis
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: user.id },
      { $set: { last_login: new Date() } }
    ).then();
    res.json({
      ok: true,
      typeAccount: accounts[user.position],
      token: user.jwtToken(),
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

Update: after looking up to your passport jwt strategy, I just notice you extract from the cookie to access to the token, and for some reason when you try to make the get request from "/auth" route, passport jwt wasn't able to extract the token from the cookie, can you check on your network tab from the Unauthorized request (401) if you can see the cookie is actually set on the request header or not ? and console.log(req.cookies) in the jwtCookieExtractor function and see what you got when you try to make get request ?
Since you re using jwt-strategy another simple approch would be simply extract from the token... that way it would make sense when you try to send the token from the header, and with this method you can skip all the workflow from the cookie because we won't need with this strategy:

```
//...
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

// I comment this up  just in case

// var jwtCookieExtractor = function (req) {
//   var token = null;
//   if (req && req.cookies) token = req.cookies.jwt;
//   return token;
// };

const jwtOptions = {
  issuer: process.env.JWT_ISSUER,
  secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
};

passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function (payload, done) {
    if (!payload.userId) return done(ApiError.Unauthorized());
    User.findOne({ _id: payload.userId })
      .populate("company")
      .exec()
      .then((user) => {
        if (!user) return done(ApiError.Unauthorized());
        done(null, user);
      })
      .catch(done);
  })
);
```

Make sure you have use the lastest version, and this is what passport jwt-strategy was made for, if we're going to use cookies to set jwtoken (which is also a good choice for security when httpOnly is set) than this package is not neccessary required.

Comment: It didn't work, I still have the same 401 error.

Comment: looks like your middleware  jwt.authenticate is still false, can you check what you got in `console.log(resp.data.token)` ? i can't figure it out since you only use passport and jwt without using passport-jwt Strategy, so i can't understand your workflow, looks like you try to set up the jwt in cookie, but try to put the jwt in the header when you fetch, why ? I am also confuse how you create and sign with  `jwtToken()`

Comment: When i `console.log(resp.data.token)`, it shows the token generated with jwt.sign located in `jwtToken()`, jwtToken() function is located in my user.js file and jwtStrategy is located in a passport.js file.

Comment: Ok I see, so it make sense you re using passport jwt-strategy that's why you use the header, and you also try to set up on the cookies.. can you redo some test in Postman, make a POST request on your /auth route which is working on your current url, copy your jwtToken on your response, and than make a GET request on your /auth route which cause trouble, and pass the token on the header write Autorization on the key, than value you put `Bearer yourjwtstringheredontforgetthespacebetweenbearerandthekey` or on the Authorization tab in Bearer Token section ?

Comment: I notice that in the browser network tag, there is a warning message that says Set-Cookie request bloqued because it had the "Secure" attribute, but it hasn't been received via secure connection, I uploaded my post so you can see an screenshot with the message.

Comment: Yea that's because I set that for cross domaine with the sameSite attribut you can remove those cookie setting for now (is "lax" by default), looks like you re in the same domaine, and since your issue is not on the cookie, but on your passport jwt strategy, did you do some test on Postman to see the behaviour ?

Comment: No, I need to set my back and front end as cross domain because they are on different servers, so they're on different domains, I can make requests on Postman and it works, is on the browser where I get the error.

Comment: Ok than this message mean you re not set your server to https, once you deploy on a secure https you won't get this message as i mension on my answer; now this issue is a headhache xD damn have to look again..

Comment: I update the answer for you do more test and see...

Comment: Actually, there's no cookie setted on the 401 unathorized request header in the network tab, I only can see the Set-Cookie header on the 200 request where it has a warning that the cookie was blocked.

Comment: Yea since for unknown reason the cookie is not send on the request header from your get method you won't be able to authenticate, did you test with the token ? as now  your Autorisation header is no use since you don't use that to authenticate.

Comment: So what can I do to solve this, bro?

Comment: the cookie is quite stricky and i am still learning so... before digging more on it have you give a try with the 2nd option I suggest, ? we need to know at least if your Bearer jwtoken work as expected or not.